# How to have count text like in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, conditional-aggregation

How to have count text like in SQL ?

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #t

Create table #t (message nvarchar(4000), messagedate datetime)

insert into #t values ('Column Listing have data error', getdate())
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:00:02';
insert into #t values ('Column Listing have name error', getdate())
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:00:02';
insert into #t values ('Column Listing have city error', getdate())

select * from #t

select count(message like 'column%') , max(messagedate) from #t
group by message
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With conditional aggregation but I don't see where you should use grouping:

```
select 
  sum(case when message like 'column%' then 1 else 0 end) counter, 
  max(messagedate) maxdate
from #t
```

If you also want the max date only for the messages that are like 'column%':

```
select 
  count(*) counter, 
  max(messagedate) maxdate
from #t
where message like 'column%'
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2bf6c182017bc954bdb17644a9788a3b).
Results:

```
> counter | maxdate            
> ------: | :------------------
>       3 | 16/04/2019 16:50:25
```

Answer (score 0):

Throw the logic part into a subquery, then just count in the main query..

```html
SELECT Message, COUNT(Message) as MessageCount, MAX(MessageDate) as MaxMessageDate
FROM (SELECT Message, messagedate FROM #t WHERE Message LIKE 'column%') a
GROUP BY Message
```